# Null Intersection

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose that $B_{\epsilon}=(0,\epsilon]$ and the family of sets $\left \{ B_{\epsilon} \right \}_{\epsilon>0}$.

We want to show that $\cap_{\epsilon >0}B_{\epsilon}=\emptyset$.

Let $x\in \cap_{\epsilon >0}B_{\epsilon}$$\implies \forall \epsilon >0 , \  x \in B_{\epsilon}$$\implies\forall \epsilon >0, \ 0<x\leq \epsilon \ \ \ \ \
 \ (*)$

And my problem is, how we can conclude from $(*)$  $0<x\leq \epsilon$ that the intersection is the null set??

Comment: What if $\epsilon = x/2$?

Comment: Oh , now I see , thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x$ is in the intersection. Then, for all $\epsilon>0$, $0<x\leq \epsilon$. Consider $\epsilon=x/2$. By assumption, $0<x\leq x/2$, which is impossible. Hence, our supposition that there was an element in the intersection in the first place is false. Hence, the intersection is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x > 0$. Then there exists a $\epsilon > 0$ with $\epsilon < x$ and thus $x \not \in B_\epsilon$. Therefore $x \not \in \bigcap_{\epsilon > 0}  B_\epsilon$. For $x \leq 0$ you obviously even have $x \not \in B_\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ and thus $x \not \in \bigcap_{\epsilon > 0}  B_\epsilon$. Hence we achieved $\bigcap_{\epsilon > 0}  B_\epsilon = \emptyset$